# Why SQL Server 2008 R2 do full installation for just adding another instance on the same machine

Tags: installation, sql-server-2008-r2

Why SQL Server 2008 R2 does a full installation for just adding another instance (only database engine) on the same machine? I thought it will be quick a installation, but it's not. What is SQL Server doing, copying/registering all the files again for this new instance?

Please clarify me.

Comment: Which version of Sql Server was already installed in your machine?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually Sql server has two types of component\features.
1.  Instance specific features
2.  Shared Features
And `Database Engine`, `Analysis Services`, and `Reporting Services` are part of instance specific features which has to copy many files for installing new instance.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143786.aspx

Answer (score 5):

> An instance, whether default or named, has its own set of
>   program and data files, as well as a set of common files shared
>   between all instances of SQL Server on the computer.
>
> For an instance of SQL Server that includes the Database Engine,
>   Analysis Services, and Reporting Services, each component has a full
>   set of data and executable files, and common files shared by all
>   components.

More Reading

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143547(v=sql.105).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is an advantage to this that will become apparent once the system has been running for a while: you can have both instances running at different release levels.

Imagine encountering a bug that is creating problems in one of your applications. There is a hotfix available, but you are not sure whether or not it will create a problem in your other applications. Simply create a new instance, install the patch and move your database over. It's not something I would enjoy doing, but it may be necessary.